# Merging uncommitted files from a branch into master

Tags: git, git-branch

In git I created a new branch `feature-scheduling` and made some changes. I have not committed any of the changes though *(all uncommitted)*.

I want to merge some *(not all)* of the changed files in the branch `feature-scheduling` into `master`, keeping the changes in both the branch and master.

How is this done?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot do it without committing the changes.  Do so in two separate commits, with the earlier containing all the updates you want to merge into `master`.  Switch to the `master` branch (this is why you need to commit *all* the changes) and perform a `git merge <ID-of-the-first-commit>`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

Create two commits on the branch. The first with all the changes I want to merge into `master`. The second with everything else.

Then:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 2
```

Note the second hash, this is needed for merging.

```
git checkout master
git merge {hash of commit from above}
```